# Why are my colum contents missing padding to the left, and have extra padding to the right?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend

Edit: Here's the codepen https://codepen.io/maptik/pen/bGKMgpJ

I'm making a react project and I'm trying to use bootstrap to render cards for each item "Producto".

This is how I'm rendering it (I've omitted some of the product details so it's easier to read):

```js
<div className="container bg-color-tienda">
  <div className="center">
    {isLoading ? <h1>CARGANDO PRODUCTOS</h1> : null}
    {!isLoading && productos && productos.length === 0 ? (
      <h5>No hay productos</h5>
    ) : null}
    {!isLoading && productos && productos.length > 0 ? (
      <div className="row">
        {productos.map((producto) => {
          return (
            <div className="col" key={producto.id}>
              <div className="single-producto">
                <div className="card">
                  {/* Thumbnail */}
                  <div className="producto-thumb">
                    {producto.publico === false ? (
                      <div className="producto-tag">No Publicado</div>
                    ) : null}

                    <div className="recipe-image-box">
                      {producto.imageUrl ? (
                        <img
                          src={producto.imageUrl}
                          alt={producto.name}
                          className="recipe-image"
                        />
                      ) : null}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    ) : null}
  </div>
</div>;
```

The thing is, my custom CSS seems to be messing with the column system. The left padding seems to be missing, while the right padding has increased. This is what it looks like:
[image]

As you can see, the left padding is nowhere to be seen, while the right padding is.

This imparity is fixed when I remove this item from my custom CSS, which I use :

```css
.single-producto {
  width: 350px;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Result:
[image]

I hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: Can you re-create this in codepen, including the non-custom CSS?

Comment: I'll try right now.

Comment: Here it is: https://codepen.io/maptik/pen/bGKMgpJ

Comment: There's no issue with padding in your codepen

Comment: Really? I see the same problem. The cards are being pushed to the left, leaving a space to the right. They don't fit in the container properly. For clarity, the cards should be centered inside the orange box.

Comment: You started off saying that padding is the issue, and in the screenshot you've demonstrated it by showing the left padding of div.col is 0, in the codepen the padding on either side of div.col is 12px. Also, the custom code has no padding in it to override the bootstrap CSS with.

So... you want it be like screenshot No.2?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249875/discussion-between-morgan-feeney-and-mats).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if this is your desire output... you just need to change the width to 100% on .single-producto class

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! It was so simple it makes me feel ashamed, but incredibly happy. Thank you!